# Getting "node stack overflow" when cbind multiple sparse matrices

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have 100,000 sparse matrices("dgCMatrix") store in a list object. The row number of every matrix is the same(8,000,000) and the size of the list is approximately 25 Gb. Now when I do:

```
do.call(cbind, theListofMatrices)
```

to combine all matrices into one big sparse matrix, I got "node stack overflow". Actually, I can't even do this with only 500 elements out of that list, which should output a sparse matrix with a size of only 100 Mb.

My speculation for this is that the *cbind()* function transformed the sparse matrix to a normal dense matrix and thus cause the stack overflow?

Actually, I have tried something like this:

```
tmp = do.call(cbind, theListofMatrices[1:400])
```

this works fine, and tmp is still a sparse matrix with a size of 95 Mb, and then I tried:

```
> tmp = do.call(cbind, theListofMatrices[1:410])
Error in stopifnot(0 <= deparse.level, deparse.level <= 2) : 
  node stack overflow
```

and then the error occurred. However, I am having no trouble doing something like:

```
cbind(tmp, tmp, tmp, tmp)
```

thus, I believe it has something to do with do.call()

Reduce() seems to solve my problem, though I still don't know the reason why do.call() crushes.

Comment: This reminded me of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035982/directly-creating-dummy-variable-set-in-a-sparse-matrix-in-r . Perhaps something in there that can help

Comment: @user20650 Did you figure out the issue that gives you the error in that post?

Comment: Well, I actually never reported the issue. But from [Ben's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035982/directly-creating-dummy-variable-set-in-a-sparse-matrix-in-r#comment35209562_23044219) you could try `Reduce`, or you could try building it out of its `i`, `j`, `x` components, re Flodels

Comment: Some additional info may help people suggest alternatives: How many columns does each matrix have? Approximately, how sparse? How much ram are you working with?

Comment: you should add the `Reduce` solution as an answer, so it is easier for others to find.

Comment: oh, and from looking a R-devel (https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=294&aid=6325&group_id=61 and https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2016-May/072682.html it is known

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in `do.call()` but due to the way `cbind` from the Matrix package is implemented. It uses recursion to bind the individual arguments together. For instance, `Matrix::cbind(mat1, mat2, mat3)` is translated to something along the lines of `Matrix::cbind(mat1, Matrix::cbind(mat2, mat3))`.
Since `do.call(cbind, theListofMatrices)` is basically `cbind(theListofMatrices[[1]], theListofMatrices[[2]], ...)` you have too many arguments to the `cbind` function and you will end up with a recursion that's nested too deeply and it will fail.

Thus, [Ben's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035982/directly-creating-dummy-variable-set-in-a-sparse-matrix-in-r#comment35209562_23044219) to use `Reduce()` is a good way to work around that issue since it avoids the recursion and replaces it with an iteration:

```
tmp <- Reduce(cbind, theListofMatrices[-1], theListofMatrices[[1]])
```

Comment: excellent insight. indeed the stack overflow is from the nesting of `cbind`.

Answer (score 0):

In R:  a 2-column matrix can have up to 2^30-1 rows =  1073,741,823 rows. So, I would check the row number and check the RAM size to make sure it can accommodate the big matrix size.

Comment: that's a _physical matrix_'s limitations; such limitations should not apply to a sparse matrix, unless it is converted to be dense somewhere along the line (though _printing_ the object may induce an error)